# Mongoose E11000 Duplicate Key with not unique username field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm having this issue. I made a login system which works like that:

1. Login with Discord
2. If exists - if user changed their Discord information, update and return user information. If they didn't change any of their Discord account information, just return user information
3. If doesn't exist - create user and return user information

That's my `user.js` schema:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  username: {type: String, required: true, unique: false},
  type: {type: String, required: true},
  discrim: {type: String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
  avatar: {type: String, required: true},
  banned: {type: Boolean, required: true}
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
export default User
```

And there's login system login (just a prototype to show the problem):

```js
app.post("/login-test", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({"userId": req.body.uid}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
    if(result == null){
      const newUser = new User({
        userId: req.body.uid,
        username: "sharek1234",
        discrim: "1236",
        email: "sharekxass@gmail.com",
        avatar: "bereknone",
        banned: false,
        type: "user"
      })
      newUser.save().then((resp) => {
        res.json(resp)
      })
    }else{
      User.updateOne({"userId": req.body.uid}, {
        discrim: "1236",
        email: "sharekxass@gmail.com",
        avatar: "bereknone",
        banned: false,
        type: "user"
      }).then((resp) => {
        res.json(resp)
      }).catch((pog) => {
        console.log(pog)
        res.json(pog)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

But when I try to log in with existing user after Discord account information change, where other user with name "MyName123" already exists, for example:
Before change:

```
UserID: "12345"
Username: "MyName"
Discrim: "1000"
```

After change:

```
UserID: "12345"
Username: "MyName123"
Discrim: "9999"
```

it returns E11000 error.
`E11000 duplicate key error collection: ShardDB.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: "MyName123" }`. Please note that `username` field in `userSchema` is not unique.

I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, I don't know why but there was "username_1" index in my database, and it was set to unique. I deleted it and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is fixed, but in case someone else is having this issue, it's because that column was unique, and then was changed, hence the index was already created.

Just like OP mentioned, deleting the index would fix the issue.